# How to do camera calibration for Primesense?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,

I want to calibrate my Carmine 1.09 depth sensor. I am using a tutorial "How to Calibrate a Monocular Camera" in ROS.

It asks me to find the topic "/camera/image_raw". However, I don't have such topic, instead I have following similar topics

```
"/camera/depth/image_raw"
"/camera/depth_registered/image_raw"
"/camera/ir/image_raw"
"/camera/rgb/image_raw"
```

I tried to calibrate the camera using "camera/depth/image_raw" with the following command:

```
rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 8x6 --square 0.108 image:=/camera/depth/image_raw camera:=/camera/depth
```

Is this command correct? If I run this command, I get a message like this:

```
Waiting for service /camera/depth/set_camera_info ...
Service not found
```

Do I need to make any changes to the code in cameracalibrator.py? Please let me know the right way to calibrate?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/111626/how-to-do-camera-calibration-for-primesense?/) by [Keerthi Raj](https://answers.ros.org/users/8061/keerthi-raj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2013-12-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2013-12-20**:
Without knowing much about camera calibration, it seems that the tutorial is talking about calibration of a grayscale/color camera, not a depth camera. So for calibration of the primesense rgb camera you might want to rather use "/camera/rgb/image_raw"? How to calibrate the depth is another story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For a camera to be calibrated and its images corrected by the image pipeline, the camera driver should publish a `camera_info` topic (with the current calibration in CameraInfo message) and provide a `set_camera_info` service (to update the current calibration).

If you are using the [openni driver](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_camera), they should be provided. In your case `/camera/rgb/camera_info` and `/camera/rgb/set_camera_info`.

Are the topic and the service there? What driver are you using for the camera?

Please note that there is a newer version of the driver: [openni2_camera](http://wiki.ros.org/openni2_camera) solving some issues with cameras not working properly with the former version. This is discussed in [question 54747](http://answers.ros.org/question/54747/primesense-carmine-doesnt-work-but-asus-xtion-does-openni-launch-devices-connected-but-not-found/).

---

Originally posted by [joanpau](https://answers.ros.org/users/893/joanpau/) with karma: 191 on 2013-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Keerthi Raj](https://answers.ros.org/users/8061/keerthi-raj/) on 2013-12-22**:
Thanks joanpau. I ran the calibration for "camera/rgb/camera_info". But, when I hit the calibrate button, the display window hangs and the respective terminal also hangs and calibration will not end. Any idea why this happens?

**Comment by [Keerthi Raj](https://answers.ros.org/users/8061/keerthi-raj/) on 2013-12-23**:
It worked. It was taking lot of time to process and my PC didn't respond for some time. So, I thought it was hung.
Anyways, I was able to calibrate the camera. Thank you very much.

**Comment by [joanpau](https://answers.ros.org/users/893/joanpau/) on 2014-01-20**:
So from your comment I guess that the remapping of the camera namespace was wrong, wasn't it? In that case, you should consider accepting the answer (I always forget to do it, too ;-).